# How to show/hide columns based on certain values in ASP.Net Core?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

So I have the following model class:

```
    public class Release
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public string OwnerId { get; set; } 
    public string OwnerName { get; set; }
    public bool Finished { get; set; }
    public bool InProgress { get; set; }
    public bool Aborted { get; set; }
}
```

Which will be visualized like this:

[image]

I want to hide and show the `Start`, `Stop` and `Finish` buttons, depending on certain values. For example:

If `Finished` is `true`, all buttons will be hidden.

If `InProgress` is `true`, `Stop` and `Finish` buttons will be visible and the other one will be hidden.

If `Aborted` is `true`, `Start` will be visible while `Stop` and `Finish` will be hidden.

I am quite a beginner when it comes to the UI part so I couldn't figure a way to do this. Below is the code for the 3 columns containing the buttons I talked about.

```
            <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" asp-action="InProgress" asp-route-id="@p.Id">Start</a></td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" asp-action="Abort" asp-route-id="@p.Id">Stop</a></td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" asp-action="Finish" asp-route-id="@p.Id">Finish</a></td>
```

What should I do in order to achieve this?

Comment: You can simplify this down to two buttons. Start/Stop and Finish. You don't have a case where start and stop are both present at the same time so just have a button that acts as both and update it accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add if statement lke this:

```
@if (p.InProgress == true)
{
 <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" asp-action="InProgress" asp-route- 
 id="@p.Id">Start</a></td>             
}
```